# "Interlocked Singly Linked Lists" Linux equivalent

Tags: linux, multithreading, linux-kernel

Is there any Linux equivalent to windows "[Interlocked Single Linked Lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684121(v=vs.85).aspx)", hence, is there an existing construct enabling list access in an Interlocked fashion ( and not using a kernel synchronization object such as a mutex ) ?

Comment: My advise is best to learn about Linux synchronization primitives, first, before asking for something equivalent to that in windows world.   Concept of "equivalency" is very much subjective from person to person.